# Why do I get the wrong value when I click on a grid row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to select a GridView row, and save its id to a variable, then use this id in a hyperlink to delete the row.

The problem is that the id=9 all the time, even without clicking on any row.

Here is the code:

```
 string id;

  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         e.Row.Attributes.Add(
             "onmouseover",
             "this.style.cursor='Pointer';this.style.backgroundColor='Yellow'");
         e.Row.RowIndex.ToString())); 

         id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ProductionOrderId").ToString();
     }
  }
```

Here is the hyperlink code

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Producter/Delete?id=" + id) %>' ID="HyperLink1">Delete</a>
```

here is the delete function should be

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
public class TEstController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /TEst/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var list = from d in db.Orders
                   select d;
        ViewData["list"] = list;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(Object id)
    { 

    // TODO
        // Delete thr user which its id = obj.id ; 

        return View();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It looks like your string id is being set repeatedly and only holds the final value, but the code was edited a few times. Is this the code you are using now?

Comment: this is the code i use. U have right, i have 9 rows in my gridview

Comment: You need to get the row ID in the view, not pass it forward. Each time a row is bound it is overwriting your previous value. I can't remember how to do this off the top of my head, but you don't need the OnRowDataBound event, you should be able to get the ID of the row without the `DataBinder.Eval` call just by accessing a property in your hyperlink code (In place of the `id` variable that is being used now)

Comment: Plese remember how to do that, or give any hint

Comment: can you put  **ResolveUrl** code

Comment: OK, been  a few years since I messed with a GridView, but see if my answer helps...

Comment: @simplecoder  now its up

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this, get rid of the event, you shouldn't need to do anything special because all you want in this case it to access the ID value.

In your template code, where you use the ID:

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Producter/Delete?id=" + id) %>' ID="HyperLink1">Delete</a>
```

Do this instead:

```
<a href='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Producter/Delete?id=" + Eval("ProductionOrderId")) %>'>Delete</a>
```

Comment: got this wrong


Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: Right, and your template should be in such a context, no? Where is the actual hyperlink code? If you are creating the view using markup, in your `Columns` element it would be a `<asp:TemplateField>` element with an `<ItemTemplate>` if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is only to get the id you should get it like this :

```
id = e.Row.DataItem["ProductionOrderId"].ToString();
```

Beware of testing the `e.Row.DataItem["ProductionOrderId"]` value, because call a `ToString()` method on a null object raise an exception.

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to this expression